# 2 Columns. How to Make the Right Even Down?

Tags: html, css, embedded-ruby

I'm trying to turn this index file into two columns where the left side is the value names (i.e. "Be the change you wish to see in the world") and the right side are their respective categories, edit paths, and delete paths.

Ideally I'd like the value attributes to not shift according to the length of the value name, but instead be fixed. It should also be fixed to the first line of the name (if the name is really long the name would line break until finished).

I hope I didn't make it sounded too complicated. I think it should be simple I've just had a hard time finding the answer. Thanks for any help given!

```html
<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->
<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading">Values</div>
  
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p>Subjective, Non-Measureable, Inspirational and/or Helpful</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Table -->
  <table class="table">
    <% @values.each do |value| %>
      <% if value.user == current_user %>

        <td><%= value.name %></td>
             
        <td>
          <b><%= value.categories %></b>
          <%= link_to edit_value_path(value) do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to value, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          <% end %>
        </td>

      <% end %>
  <% end %>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `<tr>`'s (table rows)

```
<table class="table">
    <% @values.each do |value| %>
      <% if value.user == current_user %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= value.name %></td>

        <td>
          <b><%= value.categories %></b>
          <%= link_to edit_value_path(value) do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to value, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          <% end %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
 </table>
```

Read more about html table http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp (I don't usually refer to w3schools but its ok just to get the gist of it)

There are some more elements to the table but they aren't commonly used as tr and td

Here is an example for how you can control the td width to make sure it doesn't line-break

http://codepen.io/Vall3y/pen/gbwKmX

remove the rule

```
.category {
  width: 100px
}
```

And the line will break

Line breaks in table only happen if there is space restrictment if I remember correctly, so you need to figure out the situation

Comment: Thank you that got me closer! But now there is a line break between the category (depending on the name length i.e. "tip" keeps it all on one line, but "principle" breaks it into two) and the edit & delete paths. Is there any way to ensure that those attributes stay on one line? Thank you!

Comment: There are multiple ways to address those kind of problems. The most straightforward one, is to allow (using CSS) enough horizontal space so that it will support even the "worst case scenario" of a long word. If you will put up a codepen or a jsfiddle I can try and help you with that

Comment: With the embedded ruby it's hard to use those sites I think. The column just needs to be long enough to fit the words: Principle, Edit, & Delete on one line. Should I create a separate CSS file or embed it somehow into the <td>? I don't know how to format the code, but I could play around with the dimensions

Comment: You should generally never use embedded style. See the example I edited into my answer, maybe it will help.